# Recovering data from corrupted win8.1 (unbootable)

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, data-recovery

Following situation: I am trying to recover very important data from a laptop of my father which was previously running win8.1 I think. No backups existent as far as I understand. I was not there when it started failing so unfortunately I cannot give much context for the initial fail but it seems it appeared when the laptop was running and went out of battery.

What I can still do:

- get into UEFI
- get into selection from where to boot

What I wasn't able to do:

- get into menu to select safe mode booting

What I tried so far:

- automatic win-recovery -> doesn't complete, gets into blackscreen with only mouse visible at most
  -> tried hitting shift fast several times or switching screen by keyboard-shortcuts; no success
- recovery triggered by killing the booting process some times in a row -> see above
- boot from a win8.1 stick -> no success, doesn't do anything really
- may be that in my stupidity I "accidently" triggerd acer system reset at some point after autmatic recovery failed over and over again, which I forcefully killed after it didn't seem to do anything
- at some point of planless rebooting it went into recovery and where I finally had some visual feedback that windows was trying to repair things which seemed to take between 1 and 2 days but the result was again not more than cursor on black-screen
- most recent ting I did: create an ubuntu 20.04 bootable stick to try to access the data.

This lead to the following:

- Alert window ("close" as only option) *Unable to access location* when trying to access "Acer" from the file explorer with following error description:

  `Error mounting/dev/sdb4 at /media/ubuntu/Acer: Unknown error when mounting /dev/sdb4`
- tried:

  `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb4`

-> result:

```
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb4 was processed successfully.
```

-> same error as before when trying to access "Acer"

- tried:

  `sudo mount /dev/sdb4 /mnt/test -o force`

-> result:

```
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to calculate free MFT records: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

-> doesn't help me very much without access to cmd or powershell

I would highly appreciate any further ideas!

Comment: It may be that the attempted system reset has deleted / damaged some of the data you want.  Try removing the drive, put it in a carrier and see if you can read the data on another computer

Comment: You could also try using a Linux live USB on your corrupted system. If you're getting into the UEFI, then booting from alternate media may be possible,

Comment: @John unfortunately I do not have a carrier. I can try and ask around though, thanks for suggesting!

Comment: @singalongconflict as I already tried it with an Ubuntu stick I wasn't thinking that would bring me further but I'm willing to try. Thanks for suggesting!

Comment: STOP WHAT YOU ARE DOING NOW. Realise anything you attempt is likely compounding your problems.....

Comment: You should create an explicit strategy to solve the problem. First ascertain the value of the data and make a decision to send it to a recovery expert or attempt to fix it yourself. If the latter, get another PC, a spare (or large disk) and use gnu DDRescue or similar to do a bit copy if the disk. Once done, determine if the original disk is suffering physical failure. If not, you can attempt recovery, and if it fails, reset and try something else. If the disk is failing, get another disk, clone the image to it and attempt recovery.

Comment: @davidgo thanks for the input! It is much appreciated! Honestly if I come to the conclusion that I want to try it myself I don't know how I would be able to find out if a physical failure is the cause of things. Any tips on that?

Comment: @davidgo another thing. After some discussion it is now decided that the cost of a professional recovery is probably above the value so I will try to fix it myself. As I do not have enough disc-space left for the DDRescue I would have to buy a new drive. I'm not sure if it is a good idea to use an external drive for speed and loss-issues. So I'm asking myself if it would be a better idea to get a new normal drive for my PC and do this by connecting to the laptop via ethernet-cable which I never did before. Is that advisable? Do I understand correctly to use ddrescue from the ubuntu livesystem?

Comment: I'm a linux person, so my my biases will show here - DDRescue will show you if the drive is failing.  You can also look at S.M.A.R.T values to find out what the drive thinks of itself, and (in Linux at least) look at the syslog output which will show errors.

Comment: An external drive can work, but is slower and might cause some issues with different sector sizes - although it is feasible to use an external drive in a pinch.  Dont start playing arround with connecting drives via PCs via ethernet.  If you have a PC, just put the old and new drives in that - and if you are limited for sata interfaces, boot off a USB.   I don't think ddrescue comes as part of ubuntu live, but it should be practical to sude apt update; sude apt install gddrescue  to get it.

Comment: @davidgo thanks a lot again for the input! I found someone who collects old hardware who is willing to help me if I do not have the possibility to wire the drive to my PC and I have to buy additional space. It may take some time till I find the room to do all this a.t.m. but I will try to reach out to you "when it's over" so you can get your accepted answer checkmark in some way :)

Comment: [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is one of the most efficient data recovery tools that exist

Answer (score 0):

Things I've done before in desperation;-
if you have access to another Windows hdd, try adding it as a Primary HDD and using that to boot from, then access the user files on the original (if it runs at all).
If you can boot from an emergency DISK (8.1 doesn't do USB Boot without setting it up properly in advance) try booting into a DOS Window and extracting the required user folders (with their files) using DOS Commands.  Perhaps you can boot directly into a DOS session... does the PC pause at "Windows will start in x seconds"  with option for an F3 recovery and "Other Options" ?? If so, go to other options where you will find the Safe Boot and other boot options.